# Charts.Js with Asp.Net Webforms Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, chart.js

I have a pie chart in my default page that should take data from database via a webservice. I tested web service and it works fine but pie chart does not work.

My Webservice:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<OgrenciSayilariGenel> getOgrenciSayilariGenel()
    {

        List<OgrenciSayilariGenel> t = new List<OgrenciSayilariGenel>();

        string[] arrColor = new string[] { "#231F20", "#FFC200", "#F44937", "#16F27E", "#FC9775", "#5A69A6" };

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["csLeo"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string myQuery = "SELECT * FROM OgrenciSayilariGenel ORDER BY Tarih DESC";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = myQuery;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                int counter = 0;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    // Aktif öğrenci sayılarını alıp gün gün gösteriyoruz.
                    OgrenciSayilariGenel tsData = new OgrenciSayilariGenel();
                    tsData.value = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("Hepsi")) != (DBNull.Value) ? dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("Hepsi")).ToString() : "";
                    tsData.label = dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("Tarih")) != (DBNull.Value) ? dr.GetValue(dr.GetOrdinal("Tarih")).ToString() : "";
                    tsData.color = arrColor[counter];
                    t.Add(tsData);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

And this is the script that should show pie chart:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var gData = [];

            var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
                gData: gData
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "OgrenciSayilari.asmx/getOgrenciSayilari",
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess_,
                error: OnErrorCall_
            });

            //window.alert("I am here");                

            function OnSuccess_(response) {
                var aData = response.d;
                var arr = [];
                $.each(aData, function (inx, val) {
                    var obj = {};
                    obj.color = val.color;
                    obj.value = val.value;
                    obj.label = val.label;
                    arr.push(obj);
                });
                var ctx = $("#chartTotalStudents").get(0).getContext("2d");
                var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(arr);

            }

            function OnErrorCall_(response) { }
    });
```

Do you see any problem here that i can't see? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually get an error message? Or any indication at all?

Comment: It calls OnErrorCall_ function but can not see detailed error.

Comment: A call to `OnErrorCall_` indicates that the AJAX request already fails, try `console.log(arguments)` in the callback, the error should be in the 2nd and 3rd parameter.

Comment: error: function (err) {alert(window.alert(err.statusText));} says Internal Server Error. Yes.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are running into the error callback your ajax request fails, most likely your backend fails.

Make sure that you're ajax request is really working, I suggest postman, but you can also use cUrl:

```
curl 'http://yourhosthere/OgrenciSayilari.asmx/getOgrenciSayilari' 
  -H 'Pragma: no-cache' 
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' 
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' 
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' 
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' 
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' 
  --data-binary '{"gData":[]}'
```

Comment: Ok. I used Firebug and found first problem: **Only Web services with a [ScriptService] attribute on the class definition can be called from script.**

I added it but now i get a new weird error: **System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method getOgrenciSayilari.<br>Parameter name: methodName**

Comment: Last error was my bad. I used getOgrenciSayilari not getOgrenciSayilariGenel. Now i am in succes function but chart does not shown. :S

Comment: Can you actually see the correct content in a console or alert? Accessing `response.responseXML` or `response.responseText`?

Comment: Ok i got it. Yes i saw correct content in alert but chart value needs integer. I changed it to int and everything works well.